# Require.js compiling on local but no on the server

Tags: java, requirejs

I have a build.js file with only the following:

```
({
  baseUrl: 'scripts',
  out: 'build/main.js',
  optimize: 'uglify2',
  include: ['main']
})
```

when I run "r.js -o build.js" locally it all works fine and it outputs main.js inside the existing build folder.

However when I run `"java -classpath js.jar:compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js -o build.js"` on my dev environment the file doesn't get generated. I Java installed the command runs but nothing happens, no error either

This is my current directory and 2 levels inside tests I have the updated build.js [image]

Comment: have you got nodejs in your dev environment?

Comment: I can't install node for security reasons on the server so I need to rely on java command only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the load properties from [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell) to load the r.js script file.
You can look at the [build.js](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/tests/rhino/build.js) and run.js in the tests/rhino directory of the [r.js](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js) project

Example : build.js

```
var requirejsAsLib = true;
load('../../r.js');

requirejs.optimize({
    name: 'main',
    out: 'main-built.js',
    optimize: 'none'
}, function (results) {
    print(results);
}, function (err) {
    print('GOT ERROR: ' + err);
});
```

and the command line (OS X/Linux/Unix):

```
java -classpath ../../lib/rhino/js.jar:../../lib/closure/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main build.js
```

Comment: I have tried but I get "could not find or load main class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main"

Comment: Check the sample on the git project : [rhino](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js#rhino) and command line for linux or windows

Comment: By moving js.jar inside tests/rhino and adding "-o" before build.js it worked for me, so my final comand is: "java -classpath tests/rhino/js.jar:compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main dist/r.js -o build.js"